# How to combine datatimes

Tags: android, datetime, concatenation

In my app the user enters the date and then the time.  For the date a calender pops up, and for the time a clock pops up.  To store them in the database in need to combine them into one datetime which them I will convert into an int.  I have fmtDate that has the date and fmtTime that has time.  How would I combine them.

The user clicks on a textbox and a calendar pops up.  The user pick the date they want and that is fmtDate.

The next textbox the user clicks and a clock pop up.  The user pick the date they want and this is fmtTime.

I would like to concat them into newTime so fmtDate and then fmtTime.  so I can use
     int currentTime=(int) ((newTime).toMillis(true) / 1000);
and store it in the database

Comment: can you give me you Two string and what format Be clear Edit Your Question with What you have and what you want

Comment: @Samir I added more detail.  Hope it is clearer

Comment: Nop give string you want to convert in millis

Comment: String dateTime= fmtDate.toString().concat(fmtTime.toString());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to convert two Strings to a DateTime object, I suggest you do something like this.

1) Create a `java.util.Calendar` object:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
```

2) When the user selects a date by clicking on the calendar, besides printing the formatted date into the text field, also set this date into your Calendar object:

```
cal.set(Calendar.DATE, <date>);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, <month>);
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, <year>);
```

3) When the user selects a time by clicking on the clock, besides printing the formatted time into the text field, also set this time into your Calendar object:

```
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, <hour>);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, <minute>);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, <second>);
```

4) When you need to insert the date/time into the database, simply create the `java.util.Timestamp` object from your Calendar:

```
Timestamp tmstmp = new Timestamp(cal.getTimeInMillis);
```

5) Now, suppose you have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    n_id        INTEGER,
    dt_time     TIMESTAMP
);
```

Then you can insert the newly created timestamp like so:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(...);
String sql = "INSERT INTO my_table (n_id, dt_time) VALUES (?, ?)";
PreparedStatememt stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setInteger(1, 1);
stmt.setTimestamp(2, tmstmp);
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Is it supposed to show up as a funny looking number?  I used breakpoints and the tmpstp look nothing like combination of the date and time

Comment: Timestamp will be a long number - number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970.  I'm adding two lines to my answer to show how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are creating `java.util.Date` objects:

```
Date date, time;
```

...

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTimeInMillis(date.getTime() + time.getTime());
```

Java 6 has a really bad time API. If you have additional time operations I strongly recommend using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).